# It is not possible to Run Google Chrome as root

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, centos-6

I am facing one strange problem in my system.
I am using CentOs 6.2 (linux)

being root it is not possible to open Google Chrome browser.
It giving the error like this...

[image: Google-Chrome error]

Firefox is working fine in root.

but why chrome is showing the error like this?

Comment: Why would you want to run Chrome, or any browser, as root?

Comment: I could think of one valid scenario: Talking to a local webserver (eg a maintenance interface of a tomcat instance) while logged into a headless server using X11 forwarding. If you do these kinds of things, the instructions in the error message about how to do it anyway should be quite clear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit `/usr/bin/google-chrome` and add `–user-data-dir` at the end of the last line

At first it was like this

```
 39 # We don't want bug-buddy intercepting our crashes. http://crbug.com/24120
 40 export GNOME_DISABLE_CRASH_DIALOG=SET_BY_GOOGLE_CHROME
 41 
 42 exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"
```

change line number 42 to like this

> 42 exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir

That's it now you can start `google-chrome` from root

Comment: It helped me a ...

Answer (score 9):

I think the error message is self explainatory - chrome stores profile information under /home, and root has no home directory. You may need to run it with the --user-data-dir flag, and specify some location for this.

I'd note though, running a web browser as root is a HUGE security risk.

Comment: root does have a home dir, `/root`.

Comment: Well, in which case, everything else is still probably valid. Storing user data in /root sounds potentially messy tho

Comment: he's probably running it as 'sudo chrome', which would run as root in his current $HOME.   But the main point is that running as root is dangerous (BAD user! BAD!).

Comment: @progo that is true for most linux in the default install, it is NOT true for all unix systems. And whoever hardcoded "do not make any assumptions about home directories at UID 0 on a unix system, period" was wise - some systems have / as the home directory for the root user. What could possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

(or `mkdir /home/chromie`
if you don't want to use /root)

or on file manager make directories `chromie` in `/root` and in `/home`

(click)

```
Kde start menu
internet
chromium (right mouse button click)
Add to Desktop

right mouse button click on Chromium Desktop icon
->properties
->application
```

On command: type

```
chromium chromium --user-data-dir=/root/chromie/
```

or

```
chromium chromium --user-data-dir=/home/chromie/
```

Chromium now starts when you are logged in as root

Comment: I tried your method its working, but it works only once. every time i have to write this `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/chromie/`
in the terminal. any other procedure to make it permanent.